# How to Open Two Excel Files in Multiple Monitors in Windows 7 pro excel 2010?

Tags: excel, exception, excel-2007

I want to open two (or more) excel windows on different screen (extended displays), But was not able to. I tried few solutions found on Google.

One worked, that was making changes in registry and after that checking the option '**Ignore other application that use DDE**'. Now I am able to get separate excel windows but same time I get this error '**There was a problem sending the command to the program'**

How to avoid this error. Can someone help me in this?

Thanks
Ritesh

Comment: Can you not just open two instances of Excel and drag one onto the other screen? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No I tried that. You can see 2 windows on taskbar but not on screens. Only one window will display on top of others.

Comment: Ritesh, you will get a better response if you ask this question on superuser.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what works for me

1. Open your first Excel file and place it on the screen you want
2. Open a new Excel file from the Excel icon (New instance of excel needed)
3. The new file will open on top of the one you have already opened.  Drag it to the other screen
4. Drag the icon for the second Excel file INTO the new (blank) Excel document

Excel is a difficult beast sometimes

Comment: This drag solution some how is not working in my machine.

Comment: Hmmm, Alright give this a go, just tested it, open the first document, then double click the excel shortcut, and then file.. open.. etc.

Answer (score 4):

What I've done is opened up one saved excel document.  Then, instead of locating the second excel document and double clicking on it to open, I just went to the start button and clicked on Excel to open up a new blank document.  This will give you 2 excel windows.  In the 2nd excel window, open up your second excel document by going to file / open / and then browse for your 2nd excel file.
Now you will have 2 excel documents, each in their own window.

Answer (score 3):

Just follow these steps and there is no need to replace the icon (at least in Windows 7):

*Start* -> type “*run*” into the “*Search Programs and files*” and hit *Enter* -> type regedit and hit Enter:

Left column: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Excel.Sheet.8/shell/Open/commend`:

Right column {adding (space)”%1″}: (be sure to include the quotation marks when typing)

Double Click on (Default) and write – `“C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE” /e “%1″`

Right Click on Command – choose “*rename*” and add something to the name – for example 2 (commend2).

Left column: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Excel.Sheet.8/shell/Open/ddeexec`:

Right Click on the folder ddeexec and choose “*rename*” and add something to the name – for example 2 (ddeexec2)

Left column `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Excel.Sheet.12/shell/Open/commend`:

Right column {adding (space)”%1″}

*Double Click* on (*Default*) and write – `“C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE” /e “%1″`

*Right Click* on *Command* – choose “*rename*” and add something to the name – for example 2 (commend2).

No restart needed. You can do this for `.CSV` files as well. Have Fun, and please share this answer with others. If the icon is not listed, you can *right-click* and go to *Properties* on any file that you wish to open with *Excel*, click the Change… button under the *Opens With* section, Browse…, look under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Excel.exe` (or under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Excel.exe`) and *double click* the `EXCEL.exe`; You may have to check the box under the Opens With section that states “*Always use this file type…*”

Answer (score 3):

I like the registry hack a lot, but you'll have to tweak several keys /Excel.Sheet.xx/ , and it may not work for all excel file types.

I have an alternative solution:

1. Create a batch file "open_excel_new_window.bat" with :

   ```
   start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" /e %1
   ```
2. Right click on an excel file, select 'open with' > 'Choose Default Program'. And browse to the batch file you just created. You may want to tick "always use the selected program to open this kind of file"

You may repeat step 2 for all excel file types you may encounter.

There are 2 cons with this trick :

- you loose the excel icon in front of excel files (only if you ticked 'always use the selected program ...')
- there is a ms-dos windows poping-up for half a sec

The way to get rid of that is to create an exe file from your batch file : use [BatToExeConverter](http://download.cnet.com/Bat-To-Exe-Converter/3000-2069_4-10555897.html) (Freeware, dead easy to use) : select 'invisible application' and the icon you want to use for your excel files. Then, use the 'Open with' trick with your exe file.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what works for me (Windows 7 & Excel 2010):

1. Open your first excel file
2. On the task bar, right click and click on Microsoft Excel 2010 [image]
3. Everytime you did this a new window appear from which you can drag the other file and view side-by-side